# pandas installing with pip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, installation, pip

When I try to install pandas with pip I have these errors. Pip version: 21.1.2; Python: 3.9.6

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 242, in run
    options.use_user_site = decide_user_install(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 655, in decide_user_install
    if site_packages_writable(root=root_path, isolated=isolated_mode):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 598, in site_packages_writable
    return all(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 599, in <genexpr>
    test_writable_dir(d) for d in set(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\filesystem.py", line 125, in test_writable_dir
    return _test_writable_dir_win(path)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\filesystem.py", line 138, in _test_writable_dir_win
    fd = os.open(file, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_3uygm2'
```

Comment: What is the exact pip command you are using?

Comment: pip install pandas

Answer (score 0):

you should uninstall python and install it again. It might work.

Comment: is there a specific version of python or any one

Comment: the latest one.